# Configuring traffic from certain VLANs to pass through DMVPN [GNS3]

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, vpn, gns3

I have the following setup in GNS3:[image]

There are other devices to the right, but they are not needed right now. I have a DMVPN configured with Router1 as hub an Routers 2, 3 and 4 as spokes.
On the switches I have user VLANs configured as follows:

Switch1 - VLAN10;

Switch2 - VLAN20;

Switch3 - VLAN30.

Everything works fine. Now I want to add a configuration so that traffic from one VLAN, say VLAN10, always passes through the tunnel, but traffic from other VLANs (VLAN20 and VLAN30) does not. I searched extensively, but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.
Can someone tell me the commands needed for that or point me to a guide that describes it?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Configuration of Router1:

```
Current configuration : 4080 bytes
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
clock timezone EET 2 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip auth-proxy max-login-attempts 5
ip admission max-login-attempts 5
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.30.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.60.2
!
ip dhcp pool NEWPOOL1
 network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.10.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
ip dhcp pool NEWPOOL2
 network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.20.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
ip dhcp pool NEWPOOL3
 network 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.30.1
 dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip domain name Router1.net
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
username admin privilege 15 secret 5 $1$0HIq$mwZCmYYlKzNxi1qnQ6Hiq0
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
ip ssh version 2
!
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr 3des
 hash md5
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp key freeride address 0.0.0.0
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set NEW esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto ipsec profile PROTECT-DMVPN
 set transform-set NEW
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Tunnel0
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip redirects
 ip mtu 1440
 no ip next-hop-self eigrp 10
 no ip split-horizon eigrp 10
 ip nhrp authentication NHRPkey
 ip nhrp map multicast dynamic
 ip nhrp network-id 100
 tunnel source Ethernet0/0
 tunnel mode gre multipoint
 tunnel key 100
 tunnel protection ipsec profile PROTECT-DMVPN
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 ip address 20.20.20.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no ip address
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Ethernet0/1.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Ethernet0/1.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Ethernet0/1.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Ethernet0/1.60
 encapsulation dot1Q 60
 ip address 192.168.60.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
!
router eigrp 10
 network 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255
 network 20.20.20.0 0.0.0.255
 network 192.168.10.0
 network 192.168.20.0
 network 192.168.30.0
 network 192.168.60.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 100 interface Ethernet0/0 overload
!
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.60.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input ssh
!
!
end
```

Comment: Do you want the traffic from the other VLANs to go anywhere else, or do you want to drop it if it tries to go through the tunnel? Also, you should edit your question to provide the router 1 configuration.

Comment: I want traffic from the other VLANs to go to the same device that traffic from VLAN10 goes to, but through the physical interfaces, not through the tunnel interfaces.

Comment: What is the destination address or network? You should also use the `no auto-summary` command on your EIGRP configuration.

Comment: I use it, it doesn't show up for some reason in "show run".  The destinations are: Router2 - 50.50.50.2, Router3 - 60.60.60.2, Router4 - 61.61.61.2.

Comment: But what is the destination to which the tunnel points? Where do you want the traffic for VLAN 10 to go? Is all the traffic flowing through the tunnel right now? Do you need to change the route for VLAN 10, or do you need to change it for the other VLANs?

Comment: The tunnel IPs are 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.4 for routers 2, 3 and 4 respectively. I want to, for example, ping Router4 from PC1 and the ping to go through the tunnel, and if I ping it from PC2, I want the ping to go through the physical interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to use [PBR](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/qos/configuration/guide/fqos_c/qcfpbr.html) to change the route traffic.

This should redirect pings from the VLAN interfaces to the interface you want:

```
ip access-list extended VLAN10_TO_T0
 permit icmp 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 50.50.50.2 echo
 permit icmp 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 60.60.60.2 echo
 permit icmp 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255 host 61.61.61.2 echo

ip access-list extended VLAN20_AND_30_TO_E0
 permit icmp 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 host 50.50.50.2 echo
 permit icmp 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 host 60.60.60.2 echo
 permit icmp 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255 host 61.61.61.2 echo
 permit icmp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 host 50.50.50.2 echo
 permit icmp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 host 60.60.60.2 echo
 permit icmp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 host 61.61.61.2 echo

route-map VLAN10_TO_T0 permit 10
 match ip address VLAN10_TO_T0
 set interface Tunnel0

route-map VLAN20_AND_30_TO_E0 permit 10
 match ip address VLAN20_AND_30_TO_E0
 set interface Ethernet0

interface Ethernet0/1.10
 ip policy route-map VLAN10_TO_T0

interface Ethernet0/1.20
 ip policy route-map VLAN20_AND_30_TO_E0

interface Ethernet0/1.30
 ip policy route-map VLAN20_AND_30_TO_E0
```

**Disclaimer:** This is not tested; I just created it from memory.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've been trying to add the config of Router1, but it comes out as one block of text with no new lines. I tried using the Preformatted option, but nothing changes.

Comment: When you enter the text, then highlight it, and press the `{}` button at the top of the edit window.

Comment: OK, it's uploaded.